# How to have sub use $_ when parameter omitted?

Tags: perl, parameters, subroutine

How can I get a perl sub to use `$_` when the parameter is omitted, like `chr` does?  Is this the best way?

```
my @chars = map { chr } @numbers;  # example

my @trimmed_names = map { trim } @names;

sub trim
{
    my $str = shift || $_;
    $str =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Sufficient to use `my $str = shift;`

Comment: @PolarBear not it's not

Comment: as per  url  https://perlmaven.com/how-to-set-default-values-in-perl   The common way to set a default value is using the //  `sub f {
    my ($count, $other_param) = @_;
    $count //= $SOME_DEFAULT;
}`

Comment: In short: (1) a qualified "yes" I'd say (2) sub declaration must come before its use if one is to invoke w/o parens (3) that `||` would drop `0` and `''` (empty string), both possible arguments, so use `//` (defined-or). See answer for more detail

Comment: @CJ7 you can use Params::Validate package https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate  (just my view bec you mentioned you want use as char (as built function))   example  `sub foo {
    my @str = validate_pos( @_, { default => $_ } );
    print "\n @str \n";
}
foo("Batman");
my @a = (1..9); 
foreach(@a){ foo; }`

Answer (score 3):

The `$_` is directly seen in a sub called in its scope, so you can indeed just use it

```
sub trim { s/^\s+|\s+$//gr }   # NOTE: doesn't change $_
```

where with [`/r` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions) the changed string is returned and *original isn't changed*, crucial here.

However, this can be tricky and can (easily) result in subtle and very hard-to-find bugs. Here is one ready example.  If we changed the `$_` in the sub during processing, like

```
sub trim {           # WARNING: caller's data changed
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $_;
}
```

then the elements of `@names` in the caller have been changed, what is generally not expected. This is because the changed upper-scope `$_` itself is aliased in `map`'s body.<sup>†</sup>  As `$_` is a convenient default for many things we'd have to keep track of everything used in the sub. So I'd indeed first copy `$_`, or safer yet `local`ize it, in the sub and work with that.

Finally, in order to use either a passed parameter or `$_` (at the point of the call)

```
sub trim {
    my $str = @_ ? shift : $_;   #/
    $str =~ s/^\s+|\s$//gr;
}

my @trimmed_names = map { trim } @names;  # may omit () if sub declared before
```

This is because the visibility of `$_` is unrelated to the argument list in `@_` so one can also pass arguments. Here we also get the (much) safer copying of `$_`.

The `shift || $_` from the question would dismiss a `0` or `''` (empty string) in `@_`, what is in principle valid input; the `shift // $_` would dismiss an `undef`, also a possible input.  Thanks to `ikegami`'s comment on this. Thus explicitly test whether there is anything in `@_`.

While passing a variable that's `undef` isn't valid here it may be valid input in general. More to the point, the premise here is to use an argument if provided, so we should do that  and then (hopefully) detect an error from the calling code (if passing `undef` shouldn't have happened), instead of quietly side-stepping it, by switching to `$_`.

So, my answer is a qualified "yes" -- that's one way to do it; but I may find it uncomfortable to work with a codebase where user's subs mix scopes.  This example `trim` in `map` is perfectly safe as it stands, but where else may such a function wind up used?  Why not just pass arguments?

**Note**:  In order to be able to call a user-defined sub without parenthesis we must have it declared in the source *before* the point of invocation so that the interpreter knows what that bareword (`trim`) is, since without parens it doesn't have any hints.

---

<sup>†</sup> I think it's worth recalling at this point that arguments to a sub are aliased, not copied, so if elements of `@_` themselves are changed then caller's data gets changed.  This isn't directly related to `$_` but the behavior can be.

Comment: What happens if a parameter is passed to the sub?  I want it to be the same as a functions like `chr` or `print`.

Comment: @CJ7  Added to the answer how to use either a passed parameter or `$_`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_` prototype.

```perl
sub trim(_) { $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//rg }
```

Otherwise, you can simply use `$_` if no arguments were provided.

```perl
sub trim { ( @_ ? $_[0] : $_ ) =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//rg }
```

Either way,

```perl
say for map trim, @strings;
  -or-
say for map trim($_), @strings;
```

Comment: Note that using `$_[0] // $_` could lead to weird outcome if you accidentally passed an un undefined value, thus the use of `@_ ? $_[0] : $_`.